# Simplification of the boolean expression using boolean algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, boolean-algebra

Simplify the following expressions to the simplest expression using De Morgan's theorem and Boolean algebra.

ABC+A'CD+B'CD

=(AB+A'D+B'D)C

=(AB+(A'+B')D)C

=(AB+(AB)'D)C

can anyone simplify it further and explain how you got there.Thanks in advance.

Comment: We have $AB\lor ABD=AB$ (absorption), and $ABD\lor (AB)'D=D$.  So $AB\lor (AB)'D=AB\lor D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always helps to expand the terms so they include all variables .. and then reorganize, and recombine in a more efficient way, adding or removing duplicates as needed.

The key principle is:

**Adjacency**

$P = PQ + PQ'$

Starting from your second expression:

$(AB+A'D+B'D)C=$

$(ABD+ABD'+A'BD+A'B'D+AB'D+A'B'D)C=$

$(ABD+ABD'+(AB+A'B+AB'+A'B')D)C=$

$(AB+(B+B')D)C=$

$(AB+D)C$

Comment: Thanks a lot!This was very helpful!

Comment: @JarvisFerns You're welcome! :)